# Создание проекта Apache Cordova

Tags: apache, cordova

При установке командой

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

ошибок не было. Дальше в документации написано что бы создать проект

```
 $ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

появилось ошибка

```
 /usr/bin/env:node:Нет такого файла или каталога
```

проект не был создан

Помогите исправить плиз

Answer (score 1):

Решил.нужно создать символьную ссылку

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```